How to remove only one level of component prefix in Nuxt app?
Directory structure:
components
components/sections/
components/sections/profile
components/sections/profile/Sidebar.vue
components/sections/main/InformationSlider.vue

Here is what default path prefix for these components would look like, without any configuration:

<SectionsProfileSidebar />
<SectionsMainInformationSlider />

And in my case, how can I omit just the Sections prefix? So that the components usage would look like this:

<ProfileSidebar />
<MainInformationSlider />


Based on this documentation you can do this:
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  components: [
    '~/components/sections',
    '~/components'
  ],
});


And you should be able to use:
<template>
  <MainInformationSlider />
</template>

